# define height of tine mce

Tags: tinymce

I want to set height of tiny mce depending on the type of element it is initialized for. For example, I want to set height 200px for headings and use mce's default size for for paragraph and ordered and unordered lists. Also, I want to adjust height of the mce instance with the content. Instead of adding vertical scrolls, it should increase with content.

Help APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to specify **[editor_css](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/editor_css)** in the tinimce init.
There you should change the desired values.